# How can create uniqe value in map function? Its need for key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I am trying to learn JS right now. And started to make a little learning and example project.

I got an issue right now. I am studying on react route system. So I have to send a unique value to create a unique path for my pokemons (I use [pokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co/) ) but this API does not give a unique value for pokemons just gives names and URLs. A got a 20 pokemons on my Pokemon Listing page.

Now I need to unique id to send `PokemonShowComponent`. How can I find a unique id for this purpose?

```
    return (
    <div>
      <h1> Pokemon pages </h1>
      <div>
        {pokemons.map((pokemon, id) => (
          <h3 key={id}>
            <Link to={"/pokemon/${id}"}> {pokemon.name} </Link>
          </h3>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

I want an `id` parameter count like a `forEach` method and return 1 to 20 every step. Like an `i++`.

It can be possible?

---

NOTE: Pokemon variable comes this lines of code.

```
const fetchPokemons = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/");

    const pokemons = await data.json();
    console.log(pokemons.results);
    setPokemons(pokemons.results);
  };
```

Comment: With the code that you have written, are  you facing any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{pokemons.map((pokemon, id) => (
    <h3 key={id}>
        <Link to={"/pokemon/${id}"}> {pokemon.name} </Link>
       </h3>
   ))}
```

your second parametr `id` should work

But I think you will need to do `` {`/pokemon/${id}`} `` instead of quotes

Answer (score 0):

You already have a unique id in your map, this is the second parameter:

```
{pokemons.map((pokemon, id) => (
```

id will return a value that starts at 0 and increments automatically

Comment: I solved the problem. I forget the ` this mark :) 
But I got a another question for you. Can I add another parameter after `pokemon`, `id`.  Have can use those usefull

Comment: No, map takes 2 parameters: element and index

Comment: Why would do need another parameter for?

Comment: Just a second, I thought something but now I realize it's just a dummy thing. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 0):

Set an initial count in your state.

You can rely on it to limit the amount of cards to displayed or for anything at all. Use your state to your disposal, no reason to make it harder on yourself.

There are a number of ways you could go about this though. even css based.